# Convert JSON to EXCEL(xlsx) and save UTF-8 don't work (Python)

Tags: python, json, pandas, utf-8, openpyxl

My code in python don't work to convert my json file to exel in UTF-8, and my excel return this caractere '�', for uppercase and accented for eg.: 'Á'. My code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook

caminho = "C:/Users/Braian/Documents/Área de Trabalho/Braian/VS Code/appAPI/JSON/Cliente"
lista_arquivos = os.listdir(caminho)

lista_datas = []

for arquivo in lista_arquivos:
    # Descobrir data arquivo
    if ".json" in arquivo:
        data = os.path.getmtime(f'{caminho}/{arquivo}')
        lista_datas.append((data, arquivo))

    # data inicial = 01/01/2021
    # data1 = 02/01/2021 -> 10.000
    # data2 = 12/02/2021 -> 150.000

lista_datas.sort(reverse=True)
ultimo_arquivo = lista_datas[0]

# Abaixo eu irei converter o arquivo Json em XLSX

print("\nConvertendo seu arquivo em Json para Xlsx...")

# Obtém os dados que eu preciso
with open(os.path.join(caminho, ultimo_arquivo[1]), encoding='utf-8-sig') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']['rows'])

# Seta o nome do arquivo
nome_arquivo = f"{caminho}/Cliente.xlsx"

# Cria um objeto Workbook do openpyxl
workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

# Adiciona os dados ao Worksheet
for row_data in data['data']['rows']:
    worksheet.append(list(row_data.values()))

# Salva o arquivo
workbook.save(nome_arquivo)

print("\nArquivo em Xlsx foi finalizado!")
```

And i try convert in more encoding, for exemple "UTF-8", "UTF-16", "LATIN-1" and more.

Comment: Try *removing* `encoding='utf-8-sig'`. The problem is in the source text file, not Python, Excel or Windows. Windows is natively Unicode. So are Python 3 strings. Excel files (xlsx) are ZIP packages containing XML files encoded in UTF8. I suspect the source file was saved as ASCII or more specifically, in the codepage of the current user's locale. `open`'s default encoding will use that default locale. If the files came from a client, try using `chardet` to determine the actual encoding

Comment: If the source file was UTF8 you wouldn't have any problems. If it was UTF16 you'd get *two* mangled characters for every source character. That means the file uses a single-byte codepage

Comment: I try use a chardet, but it's doesn't work again, I have a first code that creates the json, and this json encode is UTF-8. I will share a part of the code: 

'''
# Save the archive
with open(caminho + filename, 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    json.dump(r_dict, f, ensure_ascii=False)
    print(f'The file {filename} was succeffully saved!')
'''

Comment: I am using an API that returns results in JSON format. I'm trying to save this file on my computer using the code that I shared, but I suspect that the issue might be related to the JSON configuration.

Comment: You're using the wrong encoding. You should be able to check this simply by looking at the JSON.

Comment: `I try use a chardet, but it's doesn't work again` what does that mean? What encoding did `chardet` find?

Comment: "Chardet" detected "UTF-8" encoding. I also analyzed the JSON and it's in "UTF-8" and coming from the API as "UTF-8", so I'm sure the encoding is correct, but I don't know why it's not translating correctly. I also tried using the "Aspose" website to convert it and it also produced these incorrect encodings.

Comment: It looks to me like you're reading the JSON correctly. If you `print` the data instead of writing it to a workbook, does it look Ok?